# Back dating URL query parameter exclusions

Tags: google-analytics

We excluded URL query parameters to stop Google Analytcis from counting certain URL parameters as multiple pages.

This worked but hasn't backdated the GA data, is it possible to do so?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Most (99.9%) of GA settings only affect the data coming in from the time the changes were saved. You cannot retroactively alter the data.

Comment: Thanks @vinoaj that's great.